# Finding all closed walks on a graph that traverse vertices a given number of times

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I've been trying to find a reference/algorithm for the following problem with no success.

Given a finite graph $G$ with vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ and positive integers $m_1,\ldots,m_r$, find all closed walks that goes $m_i$ times through $v_i$.

Comment: You can construct a new graph by copying each vertex mi times and connecting the corresponding copies. Your problem is then equivalent to finding all hamiltonnian cycles in this new graph.

Comment: If all of the vertices of G are given in the list of length r, the construction would work. Otherwise you are looking for a tour of a proper subset of vertices, and then it is not clear what graph you need for a Hamiltonian.  Gerhard "Exact Specification Can Help Much" Paseman, 2018.04.24.